# ios - when getting parameters from a text field, should I check for null before trimming?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios5

I am thinking of doing something like this:

```
    NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.somedomain.com?id=%@&email=%@",
[id.text stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet: [NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]], 
[emailField.text stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet: [NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]]];
```

Would that work? Or if the fields are blank, will that result in some sort of errors?

Thanks!

Comment: no need to remove white spaces, because its already empty string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the fields are blank, you are going to get a url that contains `id=(null)&email=(null)` when it is formatted.

In this case, counting on the `nil` to short-circuit the message won't work because you are not sending the message to any of the object that will be nil.

You should check both fields individually and either set them to @"" (if your API can handle that) or omit the query strings from the URL.

Answer (score 2):

For the trimming it is not required. Because sending message to null wont have any effects, At the same time you need to check whether that url is valid or not.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following method to check its null or not

```
 if ([[emailField text] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]].length ==0 ||[[id text] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]].length ==0 )
{
//Dont call api
}else{
// call api
}
```